# differences between Banach spaces and $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Can you please tell me, what are the biggest differences between Banach spaces and $\Bbb R ^n$?
I am trying to understand the Frechet derivative.

Comment: Thi biggest diffference is a dimension. Untill you are in finite dimensional world everything is fine, then a lot a of pathologies arise...

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space where elements are vectors with $n$ components like $(a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n)$. Here $n$ is finite.

In a general Banach space it may not be. There vectors may have infinitely many elements. Banach Space is a normed linear space where any Cauchy sequence is convergent.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Banach space with usual Euclidean Topology, but there are Banach spaces which are not $\mathbb{R}^n$